# Is there any other way to print solid rhombus with * using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I am leaning Java, trying to solve the patterns in Java using for loop
[Solid Rhombus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkaq4.png).

Print Format:

```
line 1 :5 Spaces *****(5 Stars) then 
Line 2 :4 Spaces *****
line 3 :3 Spaces *****
Line 4 :2 Spaces *****
Line 5 :1 Space *****
```

I tried for loop with nested for loop as below

```
public class SolidRombus {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        int m = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= m-i+1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to print same Star-pattern using only for-loop with less statements in Java?

Comment: How should the rhombus appear if height and weight are not equal?  That is, should the lower-left corner always be at column 0?

p.s. Generate the String of stars once.  Use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind for using meaningful variable names

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it:

```
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(" ".repeat(i) + "*".repeat(5));
}
```

The `repeat` method on the String object is "new" since Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

You do it almost right. Just one tiny mistake in the first loop.

```java
public static void printSolidRhombus(int height, int width) {
    String stars = "*".repeat(width);

    while (height-- > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
            System.out.print(' ');

        System.out.println(stars);
    }
}
```

When you call `printSolidRhombus(5, 7)` you get:

```
     *******
    *******
   *******
  *******
 *******
```

***P.S.** I would remove on space column from the patter, to make the last row like `*******`*

Answer (score 0):

You could do it recursively without any loops:

```
static void recursive(String prefix, String suffix) {
  System.out.println(prefix + suffix);
  if (prefix.length() > 1) {
    recursive(prefix.substring(1), suffix);
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  recursive("     ", "*****");
}
```